# is this code right?

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a hangman code on scala. So, I wrote the following code for making an array that the length of elements are determined by args. For example, there exists an array B = Array("scala", "python", "C++", "Pascal", "java") and from this array I want to make an array that has an elements only of length 6. The following is the code I wrote:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.util.Random
val fname = args(0)
val listOfwords = Source.fromFile(fname).getLines.toArray
val temp = Array("a")
val a = args(1).toInt

def new_array{
for (i <- 0 until listOfwords.length-1){
    var length = listOfwords(i).length.toInt
    if (length == a) {
        temp :+ listOfwords(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes advantage of the new Scala 2.8 collections... Should do what you want.

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.util.Random

val fname = args(0)
val listOfwords = Source.fromFile(fname).getLines.toArray
val a = args(1).toInt

val new_array = listOfwords.filter(elem => elem.length == a)

// or you can use this
val new_array = listOfwords.filter(_.length == a)
```